# Android Share Content OnClick Listview

Tags: android, share

I have a listview and write a code block its okay and cancel button :

```
builder.setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();

                    }
                });
                builder.setPositiveButton("Share This Content", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Notification note = new Notification();
                        note.shareMessage("",answer);                            
                    }
                });
```

and

```
 public void shareMessage(String title, String message) {
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    String shareBody = title;
    String copied = "\n\n Osmanlı Medrese İlimleri Uygulaması - Google Play ";

    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, message);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody + copied);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Paylaş"));
}
```

and this is logcat

```
12-26 20:14:56.584    2889-2975/com.islamiceducationquestions.v1 D/libc﹕ [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn 13(0x6170692e706172),sn(),family 0,flags 4
12-26 20:14:56.584    2889-2975/com.islamiceducationquestions.v1 D/libc﹕ [NET] getaddrinfo-,err=8
12-26 20:14:56.584    2889-2975/com.islamiceducationquestions.v1 D/libc﹕ [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn 13(0x6170692e706172),sn(),family 0,flags 1024
12-26 20:14:56.584    2889-2975/com.islamiceducationquestions.v1 D/libc﹕ [NET] getaddrinfo-, 1
12-26 20:14:56.584    2889-2975/com.islamiceducationquestions.v1 D/libc﹕ [NET] getaddrinfo_proxy+
12-26 20:14:56.614    2889-2975/com.islamiceducationquestions.v1 D/libc﹕ [NET] getaddrinfo_proxy-, success
12-26 20:14:56.614    2889-2975/com.islamiceducationquestions.v1 I/global﹕ call createSocket() return a new socket.
12-26 20:14:56.614    2889-2975/com.islamiceducationquestions.v1 D/libc﹕ [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn 13(0x35342e3136342e),sn(),family 0,flags 4
12-26 20:14:56.614    2889-2975/com.islamiceducationquestions.v1 D/libc﹕ [NET] getaddrinfo-, SUCCESS
12-26 20:14:58.024    2889-2975/com.islamiceducationquestions.v1 D/libc﹕ [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn 13(0x6170692e706172),sn(),family 0,flags 4
12-26 20:14:58.024    2889-2975/com.islamiceducationquestions.v1 D/libc﹕ [NET] getaddrinfo-,err=8
12-26 20:23:07.354    4391-4391/com.islamiceducationquestions.v1 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4165ee30)
12-26 20:23:07.354    4391-4391/com.islamiceducationquestions.v1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.islamiceducationquestions.v1, PID: 4391
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3505)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3466)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3708)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3676)
        at com.islamiceducationquestions.v1.Notification.shareMessage(Notification.java:94)
        at com.islamiceducationquestions.v1.MainActivity$PlanetFragment$2$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:347)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5633)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:896)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:712)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-26 20:24:30.434    4391-4391/com.islamiceducationquestions.v1 D/Process﹕ killProcess, pid=4391
```

Comment: Can you post the code of Notification class as `shareMessage` looks OK?

Comment: What did you mean? There is already shareMessage method. @Jay

Comment: I want to see what is there in Notification class. Is that an Activity?

Comment: Please post complete logcat trace. Partial is useless.

Comment: Yeah Notification extends Activity @Jay

Comment: @Jay: That can't be the problem. Its same as setting action

Comment: Updated logcat message @Rohit5k2

Comment: Can you point the line number 94 of `Notification.java` class

Comment: This is where it gives error : Line 94 : startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Paylaş")); @Rohit5k2

Comment: You can't create instance of any class that extends activity like you did for Notification. Movie the method shareMessage to MainActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed method of Notification class to MainActivity class where it is called:

public void shareMessage(String title, String message) {

```
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    String shareBody = title;
    String copied = "\n\n Osmanlı Medrese İlimleri Uygulaması - Google Play ";

    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, message);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody + copied);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, getString(R.string.share)));
}
```